# Can I tile over white paint?

Tags: concrete, flooring, tiling, paint-removal

Through out the house there is this white substance on the concrete that looks similar to white paint. There use to be carpet with the first owner of the house hence the brown glue, and then there was laminate wood.I want to make sure the adhesive that I am going to use has the best bond to the concrete and tile as possible. Do I need to remove this substance before tiling and if so do I use something like paint thinner or use a thinset grinder?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That most likely _is_ white paint.  If it's concentrated around doorways and other areas with a lot of trim, it's probably oil based paint that was sprayed on the trim.  No need to mask off the floor if you're laying carpet, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am laying tile and yes its around the trim of the room.

Comment: Oh, I was saying the builder of the house didn't mask the floor because they were laying carpet.  I have this same issue in my house, and I'm not sure what the "best practice" is because of the difficulty in removing the paint.  Looking forward to some answers.

Comment: Lol, I understand now.

Comment: You need to get that paint off. Try a orbital sander with 40 grit disc. Attach the sander to a vacuum with a good filter and a bag.   Or rent a buffer with a pad and some 100 grit screens. It’s Gona make a lot of dust